# removeClass com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera uso o seguinte código em jQuery para remover uma classe de uma `TR` de uma tabela.

```
$("tr").removeClass('text-white');
```

Funciona muito bem, porém ele esta removendo os `tr` de todas as tabelas, quero saber como faço para remover apenas da tabela da `class="dados"`.

Comment: A tabela é gerada dinamicamente com JavaScript?

Comment: sim, mas já resolvi com a ajuda do @Giovane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente `$("table.dados tr").removeClass('text-white');`

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou 100%

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, amigo.

Você consegue resolver o seu problema desta forma:

```
$("table.dados tr").removeClass('text-white');
```

Ele vai pegar todos os **tr** de todas as tabelas que contém a classe **dados**.